# Pandas: how to filter data set where today's date is greater than date field in the data set

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I'm trying to filter a data set to only show rows where today's date is greater than the Due Date. I also need the date in the table to show in the following format: mm/dd/yy. To do this I did the following:

```
df['today'] = dt.datetime.today()
df['today'] = df['today'].dt.strftime('%m%d%y)
df['Due_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Due_Date'])
df['Due_Date'] = df['Due_Date'].dt.strftime(%m%d%y)

df = df.loc[(df['today'] > df['Due_Date'])]
```

But when I do that the table shows rows with due dates both before and after today's date. I know I haven't provided a data set, so if the issue isn't clear from this then please let me know and I'll try to find a data set to use for this example. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is your df['Due_Date'] is in mm/dd/yy format?

If not try this

```
df['today'] = dt.datetime.today()
df['Due_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Due_Date'])

df = df.loc[(df['today'] > df['Due_Date'])]

df['today'] = df['today'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%y')
df['Due_Date'] = df['Due_Date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%y')
```

Comment: I did have the slashes in the code, I forgot to include it above. But wow. That worked. Thank you! Why did changing the order work?

Comment: strftime() returns datetime in string format. You need to keep df['today'], df['Due_Date'] in datetime format in order to compare or filter. Once you get the desired results, change it to the required format. In your case '%m/%d/%y'. strftime()  returns a string not datetime.